# Logstash JSON filter with mutate to add new fields

Tags: json, filter, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to fetch data from following log entry using the below logstash config file and filters, but the data isn't fetching from json instead it displays the grok pattern.

**Log:**

```
13:41:37.3921 Info {"message":"CTS execution started","level":"Information","logType":"Default","timeStamp":"2019-12-03T13:41:37.3861868-05:00","fingerprint":"29dad848-4ff7-4d2d-905b-460637f3d534","windowsIdentity":"home","machineName":"L02174400","processName":"CTS","processVersion":"1.0.5","jobId":"5bbc492c-bcb7-451f-b6ac-87d9784ad00d","robotName":"home","machineId":0,"fileName":"SendBackReasons(Autosaved)"}
```

**Config:**

```
input{
    file{
        type => "executionlog"
        path => ["c:/users/xyj/appdata/local/uipath/logs/*[^W]_execution.log"]
            start_position => "beginning"
            sincedb_path => "c:/dbfile" 
              }
}

filter{
    grok{
        match => { "message" => ["(?<id>[\d\:\.]+)\s%{LOGLEVEL:level} %{GREEDYDATA:json-data}"]
              }
         }

    json{
        source => "json_data"
        target => "parsed_json"
            }
        mutate{
            add_field => {
                    "Info1" => "%{[json_data][message]}" #i tried parsed_json as well here
                    "level2" => "%{[json_data][level]}"

                    }
            }
    }
output{
    elasticsearch{
            hosts=>["http://localhost:9200"]
            index=> "uipathexecutionlog"
               }
               stdout{}
}
```

Kibana output:
[Kibana output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUIVY.png)

Comment: In your grok config you are storing your raw json in the field `json-data` but your json filter is using a field named `json_data` as source, which does not exist. Double check your fields name and try again.

Comment: What a silly mistake, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { 
      "message" => ["(?<id>[\d\:\.]+)\s%{LOGLEVEL:level} %{GREEDYDATA:json-data}"] 
      }
  }

  json {
    source => "json-data"
    target => "parsed_json"
  }

  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "Info1" => "%{[parsed_json][message]}" 
      "level2" => "%{[parsed_json][level]}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Angel H, that typo fixed the issue.